# How to execute a POST and GET via AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I read few articles but either I couldn't fully understand the solution or I felt they did not answer my problem at hand. So I am asking here again.

I need to make HTTP requests POST, PUT and GET calls to an external service.
I would like to batch up my POST calls in AWS SQS and execute them.

Currently, the POST calls via a lambda function is working fine. But I am not sure how to leverage AWS SQS for these callouts and also how to store the API responses and/or webhook responses.

Comment: Do you mean using only SQS for making the calls or do you mean use the combination of Lambda and SQS ?

Comment: If I make POST calls to a 3rd party app from SQS it will be ideal. I am looking for an alternative to "python requests" libraries. I would like to use SQS instead. I am able to write my POST request arguments as a message payload to a QUEUE. I would like the Queue to execute the POST command. I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. SQS is just a messaging queue that is not able to make any other process. You would have to use a lambda trigger, you can configure your queue to batch your message and only trigger the lambda when you have x message available. Hope it helps

Comment: Alternatively, take a look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

Comment: This is how I have implemented it. If there are better suggestions, please let me know. A lambda function does the pre-req steps and then issues the "POST" call. The response to the POST call is queued in a SQS queue. Then I have written a Lambda trigger that will process the message. i.e. the POST request API response. The issue I was trying to avoid was this. The POST response takes 3.5 seconds for each call, we will be making about 1000-2000 calls daily. This is a lot of wasted lambda runtime which I want to avoid.